# Java - Problems creating a Map inside another Map

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I'm trying to create a program that keeps track of a bunch of different Strings, and "ties them together" with the current user's entered name (another String), meaning every person should have their own wallets. I tried to do this using a Map inside another Map, but this is where my brain overloads. How do I tie every wallet to the correct name and then display all of that? The comment in my code gives a good example of it. Here is what I have so far:

```
    Scanner sysin = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean firstTime = true;
    Map<String, Set<Long>> walletTracker = new HashMap<String, Set<Long>>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>> nameTracker = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>>();
    
    if(!firstTime) {
        /* Here it should display every entered name, wallet and time of deposit, like this:
        
        Jack:
            JacksWallet:
                [12345], [123456], [1234567]
            JacksOtherWallet:
                [123], [1234]
        Jonathan:
            JonsWallet:
                [12345678]
        */
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 1;) {
        System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
        String name = sysin.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Please enter a wallet name: ");
        String wallet = sysin.nextLine();
        
        Set<Long> deposits = walletTracker.getOrDefault(name, new HashSet<>());
        deposits.add(System.currentTimeMillis());
        walletTracker.put(wallet, deposits);
        nameTracker.put(name, walletTracker);
        
        System.out.println("You successfully withdrew money from "+ wallet +". Press enter to continue...");
        firstTime = false;
        String enter = sysin.nextLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I found & noticed:

- The `if(!firstTime) {}` block should be within the for loop, so that it actually prints on every iteration.
- You attempt to use `walletTracker.getOrDefault(name, new HashSet<>());`, but the `name` variable is not the correct variable to use here. You should be using the `wallet` input variable.

Here is my "print it out" code, that matches your recommended formatting:

```java
nameTracker.forEach((name, wallet) -> {
    System.out.println(name);
    wallet.forEach((walletName, dates) -> {
        System.out.printf("\t%s\n\t\t%s\n",
            walletName, Arrays.toString(dates.toArray(new Long[0])));
    });
});
```

Outside of this, the code you used to actually populate the map(s) is correct.

@rzwitserloot Made some good points about using OOP to your advantage, and I would recommend those suggestions as well.

Comment: I fixed my silly mistakes you pointed out, thanks. And sorry, I'm a bit confused about the print code you provided. The top line is only supposed to iterate through the Maps right? Because when I try it, it tells me that it "cannot redeclare another local variable defined in an inclosing scope". Why is it trying to redeclare them?

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue if the code provided is in the correct location. It should be contained in this block: 
`for(int i = 0; i < 1; ) { if(!firstTime) { // Print Code } // Input Code }`
This error implies that your `String wallet = scanner.nextLine();` code is conflicting with the scope of the wallet variable defined in the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Ah I see, you were absolutely right. I put it at the bottom at first, that's why it didn't work. Another problem though, now whenever you enter 2 different names and 2 different wallets, both wallets will be placed under both names instead of the two names getting their own wallet. Is this because we haven't cleared the Maps or the Set?

Comment: @enheldel This is because we check for & modify the wallet regardless of whether the person in question owns the wallet. The solution is to use one map (the master map, `Map<String, Map<String, Set<Long>>>` and only query and update that. Take a look [here](https://gist.github.com/NoEffort/b25df17b24a61bc57b53e7705667156d).

Ideally, I suggest you consider using OOP, like **rzwitserloot** suggested.

Comment: Yes, you were right, it all works now! The method you provided was also a lot easier to understand than how I had it before. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

> `Set<Long> deposits = walletTracker.getOrDefault(name, new HashSet<>());`

This returns `new HashSet<>()` if there is no mapping for `name` but it **does not** add that to the map. What you want is `.computeIfAbsent`, which will just return the mapping that goes with `name`, but if it is not there at all, it evaluates your lambda and then adds that to the map and then returns that:

```
Set<Long> deposits = walletTracker.computeIfAbsent(name, k -> new HashSet<>());
```

That's 'lambda' syntax - you don't write an expression that resolves to a new hashset, you write an expression that resolves to a function that produces a new hashset when provided with the key (which we don't need here, and is equal to `name` anyway).

Java-esque strategy here is to make a `Wallet` class at least. In general, once you start putting `<>` inside `<>, especially if you're 3 levels deep, stop, and start writing classes instead.

That should be a `Map<String, Wallet>` and a `Map<String, Person>` or whatnot.

Comment: I know that line of code doesn't add to the map. That's why I used "walletTracker.put" below that instead. The "walletTracker.getOrDefault" line is only there to get all Strings from the "wallet" variable and place them in a Set. However, I accidently put the "name" variable there instead which someone pointed out below. My bad.